# disappearing values this.state.array ReactJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, this, state

I am fetching an array with the following method:

```
module.exports = {
          fetchIntegrations(self) {
            var encodedURI = "OMITTED";
            axios.get(encodedURI).then(function (r) {
              self.setState({
                response: r.data,
              })
            })
            return self
          }
        };
```

Then I am calling this from this method:

```
_getIntegration(){
            var self = this;
            var axios = require("axios");
            axios.defaults.headers.common[ "Authorization"] = this.props.userInfo.isAuthorized

            api.fetchIntegrations(self);
            console.log("This " , this);
            console.log("This.state " , this.state);
            console.log("This.state.response ", this.state.response);

return this.state.response.map((integration) => {
    return (<NavBarItem key={integration.identifier}
             name={integration.displayName}/>);
            });
         }
```

This is the NavBarItem class:

```
class NavBarItem extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
    <div className="navbaritem">                
            <Text className="navbaritem-name">{this.props.name}</Text>
            </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The _getIntegration Method is inside of this Layout class (abridged):

```
export class Layout extends React.Component {
constructor (props) {
    super(props)
this.state = {
        response: [],
      }
  }


componentDidMount = () => {
      this._getIntegration();
  }
}
```

When this gets logged in the console, it has my response array in it with items. In this.state and this.state.response, the response array somehow contains 0 items. I tried using setState() in a few different places without luck. Ideas for how I can access my response array values? My goal is to create NavBarItems for each object in the array, however since there are no items in my response array, not much is happening :(
Thank you!!

Comment: Show your component.

Comment: The console.logs executes before the AJAX response. The fetch is asynchronous.

Comment: I wanna see where that `_getIntegration` gets called. Edit your question and include your entire component if you need help.

Comment: Edited! I am calling _getIntegration inside of componentDidMount function inside of my Layout class. I had the call just 'out in the open' of the Layout class before and it was getting called continuously - so this was my fix.

Comment: @Hoyen ok that makes sense that console logging happens before.. but how can I fix it when I try to do the mapping and it still is empty?

Comment: @LisaKaudasch your implementation approach is wrong. When you are using React's components, every time `setState` is called, the component will re-render. In the `Layout` component in the render function, you should get the array of `NavBarItem` components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should restructure the code so that the fetchIntegrations service returns a promise with the data back to your Layout component. You can put the console.log in any of the following functions: `shouldComponentUpdate, componentWillUpdate, render, componentDidUpdate` if you want to see the state of the component during each phase.

I posted an example on CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/lrvzm872v9

The main parts of are the Layout component and the fetchIntegration service:

```
class Layout extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      response: [],
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetchIntegrations().then((data) => {
      this.setState({
        response: data
      })
    })
  }

  getIntegrations() {
    const integrations =this.state.response.map((integration) => {
      return (
        <NavBarItem key={integration.identifier}
          name={integration.displayName} />
      )
    });
    return integrations;
  }
  render() {
    if (this.state.response.length == 0) { return null; }
    const integrations = this.getIntegrations();
    return (
      <nav>
      { integrations }
      </nav>
    )
  }
}
```

fetchIntegration:

```
function fetchIntegration(){
   var encodedURI = "OMITTED";
   return axios.get(encodedURI).then(function (r) {
          return r.data;
    }
}
```